# How to display rearrange control after moving rows in table view with editing enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, setediting

So I stumbled upon a rather inconvenient 'feature' of the iOS SDK last night, and I wanted to share my finding and solution with you guys. Also to get input, should there be a better solution.

**Scenario**

I had a table view set up with two sections, on for *favorite items* another for *all other items*. Tapping a row in the table view would toggle whether the item is marked as favorite; tapping a row in the *favorite items* section, would remove it from favorites, while tapping a row in the *all other items* section would add this item to the favorites.

When the state of favorite is toggled, I use `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` to do a nice little animation and move the row from *favorites* section to *all others* section.

**Problem**

So, the problem occured because, not only should the user be able to toggle favorite state, also all of the items in the *favorites* section should be rearrangeable. Thus I wanted to display a rearrange control in each row of the *favorite items* section.

However, a cell isn't redrawn when invoking `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` and fromIndexPath and toIndexPath are both in the visible area. This means that the rearrange control is not displayed when adding a new row to the *favorite items* section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

After looking through page-after-page in the documentation, thread on StackOverflow and trying out various stuff, I finally found a solution.

Immediately after calling `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` I also invoke the following lines:

```
[cell setEditing:NO]
[cell setEditing:YES]
```

Which would cause that one cell to understand that it's restriction for rearrangement has changed, thus show/hide the rearrange control appropriately.

I find this solution to be very hacky, so I'd be happy to hear about better solutions. But at least, a solution is out here now, for other people to enjoy.